# How can i test Optmistic Locking using junit, spring and JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, junit

I have my entities with a @version column, daos, and junit test.
How can i induce an optimistic lock exception in the junit test case, to see that it's handled correctly?

I am using spring transaction managamemnt, so this makes it more complicated i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open a transaction from a jUnit test method and read one row from a certain table.
2. Create a new thread and open another database transaction which will read the same row.
3. Update it, and save it to the database.
4. Pause the main thread used by the jUnit test method.
5. Modify the data read at the beginning and try updating the row. As a result an optimistic lock exception should be thrown.

Comment: Forgot to say i am using spring TX managamanent, edited now. is it possible with the tx managament?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, to open a database transaction you'll need some TX management. Bear in mind that opening two separate transactions from the same thread is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

In my current Project we have to handle the OptimisticLockException and wrap it into a coustomized exception. Instead of Spring we are using hibernate. But maybe this way will help you.

For my solution you need an OpenEJB-Container in your Test:

```
@LocalClient
public class ExampleClassTest {

    //its a self written class to bootstrap the open ejb container
    private static OpenEjbContainerStarter openEjbStarter;

    private static Context context;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    @EJB
    private ExampleWithSaveActionFacade facade;

    @EJB
    private ExampleDAO exampleDataAccessObject;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBefore() throws Exception {
        openEjbStarter = new OpenEjbContainerStarter();
        context = openEjbStarter.startOpenEJB();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdown() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        openEjbStarter.destroyOpenEJB();
    }

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        context.bind("inject", this);
    }

    @Test(expected = OptimisticLockException.class)
    public void testSaveSomethingWithException(){

        //get the first object you will manipulate and change the Version
        //current Version is 1
        ExampleModel example = exampleDataAccessObject.findById(1L);
        example.setSomeData("test");

        //get the second object what will cause the exception
        //current version is 1
        ExampleModel exampleOldObject = exampleDataAccessObject.findById(1L);

        // returnValue with the version number 2
        ExampleModel returnValue = facade.persistOrUpdateUser(example);

        //try to save the object with the version 1
        //throws the OptimisticLockException
        facade.persistOrUpdateUser(exampleOldObject);
    }
}
```